# Can you solve this doubt of tense on use of 'could' and 'were'?

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

[Biography-Shadow Dragon Saga](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gogeta)

[image]

Well.If 'they fuse into' is not used.They 'fused' is used.That may be because of 'could'.If I say 'Goku and Vegeta not being able to defeat Omega, ....' then it should have been 'they fuse into'.But if I say 'Goku and Vegeta were not being able to defeat Omega' then what would be the effect on that 'fuse'?

Comment: There are many very skilful writers in the fanatasy/gaming world, but you should not expect that every post on a public wiki will have been written by one of these. This particular post is carelessly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This narrative starts off using [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) with **suggests**, then switches to simple past with  **fused**, **overpowered**,  **used**. At the end switches back to historical present with **goads**.

The usage of simple past for **fused** has nothing to do with the use of **could**: it is just inconsistent, and some would say sloppy, writing.

Comment: Actually, it starts with an ordinary past: ***could** not beat*. But you're quite right about this being slovenly writing.